# LINQ MoreThan(predicate, limit) extension instead of Count(predicate) > limit?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, comparison, operator-keyword

What is the best way to check whether an IEnumerable collection has more than or less than X elements that fulfill a predicate?

I am currently using `.Count(lambda) <= limit` but this makes the program unnecessarily iterate over the whole collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define some extension methods:

```
static bool LessThan<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int count, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    int found = 0;
    foreach (var item in enumerable)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            found++;
            if (found >= count)
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

static bool MoreThan<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int count, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    int found = 0;
    foreach (var item in enumerable)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            found++;
            if (found > count)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and then use them like so:

```
var col = new[] { 1, 6, 4, 8, 3, 5, 1, 7 };
var res1 = col.MoreThan(2, c => c == 1); //false
var res2 = col.MoreThan(1, c => c == 1); //true
var res3 = col.LessThan(4, c => c > 5); //true
var res4 = col.LessThan(3, c => c > 5); //false
```

Comment: Very good, though probably it should be (found > count) in the first and (found >= count) in the second.

Comment: That would make them return true when the amount of matching elements is equal to the amount you're searching for, which doesn't make sense for the names "LessThan" and "MoreThan".

Answer (score 7):

You can use this expression: `.Skip(limit).Any()` equivalent `Count() > limit`. But if your list is  `ICollection`, `Count()` is more preferable.

Predicate version:

```
public static bool MoreThan<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate, int limit)
{
    int i = 0;

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            i++;

            if (i > limit)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? It's not counting elements that match a predicate like the question asks.

Comment: @Kirill, SkipWhile(predicate) will return all elements once the condition is no longer met.

Comment: @Erwin, True. I delete this from my answer.

Comment: @Erwin, If you use `.Count(predicate)`, I think it is the most appropriate solution.